# C# related on Constructor and Property

Tags: c#, properties, constructor

I am building some tiny lib, and I have run into a problem. 
I want to provide a two-way solution, for example:

How can I accomplish this? 
I am getting exception thrown, because it expects something... Any example that will do is welcomed :) Thanks!

EDIT: I am executing something, initially my code is similar to this one:

```
 System.IO.DriveInfo d = new System.IO.DriveInfo("C:");
```

I want to achieve with my class the following:

```
Driver d = new Driver(); 
d.DriverLetter = "C:";
```

And still get the same results, I use ManagementObjectSearch, ManagementObjectCollection and some other System.Management classes.

Comment: which exception do you get?

Comment: Note there is a difference between not compiling and an exception being thrown. Most people are assuming you mean "not compiling" because you have not given us enough information, namely the implementation of the `Person` class or the exception (if it truely is an exception).

Comment: I am also executing something via the constructor! This is causing some issues, is there anyway to achieve the execution via a Property. Despite that the first constructor executes, before the Property is set. ???? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the parameterless constructor version? Why not just create a new `Drive` object when you want to access a different drive letter. There is no value as far I can tell (not much code posted) in reusing a `Drive` object. Attempting to maintain a consitent state when you allow changing of things that are central to the operation of an object, in this case the drive letter, is going to generate much more code. Try making drive letter `readonly` and force it to be passed in the constructor. Read up [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and their benefits.

Comment: Sigh, you shouldn't change a question so dramatically. It basically invalidates everyone's answers that they worked on. You should open a new question with the *actual* problem you're having instead. (and don't ask one thing when your problem is really something else)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to provide both constructors:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    // Paramterless constructor  -  for   new Person();
    // All properties get their default values (string="" and int=0)
    public Person () { }

    // Parameterized constructor -  for   new Person("Joe", 16, "USA");
    public Person (string name, int age, string country)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Country = country;
    }
}
```

If you define a parameterized constructor, the default parameterless constructor is not included for you.  Therefore you *need* to include it yourself.

From MSDN [10.10.4 Default constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608.aspx):

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided.

Comment: @SonerGönül Well, we don't know it's right till it's accepted! This is assuming it's not compiling but OP is complaining about an exception.

Comment: @weston Agreed - I upvoted your comment on the question.  However, everything I said in my answer is true *and* is essential for what the OP desires.

Comment: I am also executing something via the constructor! This is causing some issues, is there anyway to achieve the execution via a Property. Despite that the first constructor executes, before the Property is set. ???? Thanks!

Comment: Of course you can "get execution via a property", they're just functions after all. What I show here are auto-implemented properties, you should look up normal properties and see that they are basically just functions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a constructor that takes those three arguments:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, string age, string country)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.Country = country;
    }
 }
```

This way, you can assign the values to the properties when the class is constructed. You can have more than one constructor for a class taking different parameters and you can have one constructor call another constructor with `: this()` syntax:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
        : this(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty)
    {

    }

    public Person(string name, string age, string country)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.Country = country;
    }
 }
```

Here the "empty" constructor will call the other constructor and set all properties to empty strings.

Comment: I am also executing something via the constructor! This is causing some issues, is there anyway to achieve the execution via a Property. Despite that the first constructor executes, before the Property is set. ???? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure it can be solved, but maybe you should update your question with some example code of what you are trying to do. That would make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string name, int age, string country)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Country = country;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person1 = new Person();
        person1.Name = "Joe";
        person1.Age = 2;
        person1.Country = "USA";

        var person2 = new Person("John", 4, "USA");
    }
}
```

The .NET Framework will implicitly provide a default/parameterless constructor *if you don't define a constructor*.  If you define a parameterized constructor, though, you need to explicitly define a default constructor too.

Comment: I am also executing something via the constructor! This is causing some issues, is there anyway to achieve the execution via a Property. Despite that the first constructor executes, before the Property is set. ???? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing your `Age` property type as `int` or `string`.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(string name, int age, string country)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.Country = country;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person("Erik", 16, "United States");

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.Name = "Erik";
        p2.Age = 16;
        p2.Country = "United States"; 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Also you need  parameterless constructor for also.

Comment: -1 Doesn't address the parameterless constructor the OP desires. Also, don't use `public` fields.

Comment: Okay, cool you finally got it. *Now* your answer looks just like mine.... what's the point?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks, updated. _Now your answer looks just like mine_ Really? Couldn't be **your** answer looks line mine?

Comment: *Are you serious?* You and I both know that your first 2 or 3 attempts didn't have the parameterless constructor, which was the whole point of the question.  Mine did from the first post. Let's not be silly here.  Maybe there's some humor I'm missing here...

Comment: Same observation as @JonathanReinhart - was just typing away before I could downvote for the same reason.  I thought I observed public fields rather than auto properties as well, but I was mistaken in the respect it seems.

Comment: @J0e3gan you are correct in both observations. See my first comment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Regarding the point, my point exactly - if I follow. :}  The explanation is as important as the code in this case I think.  If the explanation was understood, the OP wouldn't have posted the question in the first place.

Comment: "...in [that] respect it seems." :P

Comment: I am also executing something via the constructor! This is causing some issues, is there anyway to achieve the execution via a Property. Despite that the first constructor executes, before the Property is set. ???? Thanks!