# How to open a exe. file using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

hello guys can anyone tell me how to open a executable file in Visual-studio using `Button` like when i click the button it will open the calculator or notepad :)

Comment: Have you tried Process.Start? Also, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: The amount of answers on this question is pretty huge. Yukimoto Otomikuy, are you sure you used the Googles before posting this question? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

From MSDN:

> Starting a process by specifying its file name is similar to typing the information in the Run dialog box of the Windows Start menu. Therefore, the file name does not need to represent an executable file. It can be of any file type for which the extension has been associated with an application installed on the system.

Comment: `+1` for being the _fastest gun_.

Comment: Process.Start("notepadd.exe").WaitForExit(); // if you want to block the caller .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method like;

> Starts a process resource and associates it with a Process component.

```
Process.Start("calc.exe");
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

> Starting a process by specifying its file name is similar to typing
>   the information in the **Run** dialog box of the Windows **Start** menu.
>   Therefore, the file name does not need to represent an executable
>   file. It can be of any file type for which the extension has been
>   associated with an application installed on the system. For example
>   the file name can have a .txt extension if you have associated text
>   files with an editor, such as Notepad, or it can have a .doc if you
>   have associated.doc files with a word processing tool, such as
>   Microsoft Word. Similarly, in the same way that the Run dialog box can
>   accept an executable file name with or without the .exe extension, the
>   .exe extension is optional in the fileName parameter. For example, you
>   can set the fileName parameter to either "Notepad.exe" or "Notepad".

Comment: Funny, it's like every edit I make shows up in your answer.
Also funny is the fact that this isn't the first time I've said this to you.

Comment: Thankyou for all the answers :) id really appreciate it :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It is too normal because we both looked in _MSDN_ page getting better explanation for OP. But what you clearly said here; "_Hey Soner, you just copied my answer_" This is not cool at all. This is not a though question, anyone can answer it. So the answers can have nearly timestamps. It is too normal. That doesn't mean they just copied one of another answers. Stop blaming people with this kind of bad attitudes..

Comment: Right. But I just spent the last 12 minutes unsuccessfully trying to find the question this last happened on. Perhaps I'm mistaken; *if* that is the case, then I apologize.

Comment: Ah, it seems I was [not mistaken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559937/).  Soner, I understand it is easily possible for two answers on a question this simple to end up looking very similar.
However, I'm going to respectfully ask that you not continually massage your answers to look like mine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method.

Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4272/Using-Diagnostics-Process-to-start-an-external-app) on how to use it.

(credit goes to [hmemcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8205/hmemcpy) for answering this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240191/2244255))

Comment: +1 for giving credit to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the above

```
// run notepad
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");

 //run calculator
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe");
```